# Programmatically check if file is checked out in TFS

Tags: tfs

I would like to check out various files, edit them and check them back in. However, I do not wish to edit files that are already checked out so I would like to check for this before I make a call to  `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.PendEdit` method. I could go through the following procedure:

```
Call GetPendingChanges
Store the pending changes in a list
Check if the file I am about to edit is in that list
Skip the checkout if it is in the list, proceed with checkout if it is no in the list.
```

However, I was hoping that there wass there a method I could call on the to do this.  That is, one that returns a bool (or int, or enum) telling you if a file is checked out.  I have looked, but can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the permissions of the file - readonly or not. Also store them in a dict, not list. Finally, there are GUI tools which integrate with TFS and do exactly what you are trying to program. There is also a command-line way.

Comment: I just realized that I did not define the problem correctly.  The algorithm I outline was not correct. It would get *my* pending edits and checking permissions would work if I were just interested the files that I'd checked out.  However, I would like to know if the file has been checked out by anyone *at all*.  Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for any input.  Urvi

Comment: Check out this link: http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/how-to-get-the-list-of-currently-checked-out-files-in-tfs